# How do sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]) work?

Tags: c++, sizeof

When looking for a size of an array in a for loop I've seen people write

```
int arr[10];
for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]); i++){}
```

How is `sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0])` the length of the array? How does it technically work?

Comment: Add the definition of `arr` to the question otherwise it's ambiguous.

Comment: @jepio It says it is an array, and the code gets the length of the array, so it is safe to assume `arr` is an array.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

If you have an `array` then `sizeof(array)` returns the number of bytes the array occupies. Since each element can take more than 1 byte of space, you have to divide the result with the size of one element (`sizeof(array[0])`). This gives you number of elements in the array.

Example:

```
std::uint32_t array[10];

auto sizeOfInt = sizeof(std::uint32_t); // 4
auto numOfBytes = sizeof(array); // 10*sizeOfInt = 40
auto sizeOfElement = sizeof(array[0]); // sizeOfInt = 4
auto numOfElements = sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]); // numOfBytes / sizeOfElement = 40 / 4 = 10
```

[**LIVE EXAMPLE**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a4537c23520c15e7)

Note that if you pass an array to a function, the above won't work since the array decays to a pointer and `sizeof(array)` returns the size of the pointer.

```
std::size_t function(std::uint32_t a[]) // same for void function(std::uint32_t a[10])
{
    return sizeof(a); // sizeof(std::uint32_t*)!
}

std::uint32_t array[10];
auto sizeOfArray = function(array); // array decays to a pointer inside function()
```

[**LIVE EXAMPLE #2**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0d523b6b3e413dbe)

Comment: if we write "array.length", does that mean we also get the correct answer in all cases ? Or is there any exception ?

Comment: @Texas_September_2020 There is no `array.length` for C arrays. If you mean `std::array::size()`, then yes, that is the same.

Comment: You are right that for C language, there is no way to get "array.length". But, for C#, there is an a public method to get array length as follow:  "public int Length { get; }".  There are good examples for C# :  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.length?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: You do realise this is a C++ question and answer?

Comment: BTW, It's true as you wrote: in C++11 or newer versions, we can also call simply "array.size()", and that will return the exact length of the array. For the older versions of C++, we still need to do the long calculation: "sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0])". I just want to add a note about "the version C++11 or newer versions" to your comment to clarify in case someone needs to know.  It's 2020 now. So, I assume that most people are using the newer versions of C++. :-)

Comment: @Job_September_2020 array.length works in Javascript. And yes, you get the correct number of elements because Js is a high-level language unlike C++.

Comment: We could define a function like:
`template <typename T, size_t N>
size_t sizeof_array(const T(&)[N])
{
    return N;
}`

So that we can deduce the size of C arrays.

Answer (score 15):

As it is described in the C++ Standard (5.3.3 Sizeof)

> 1 The sizeof operator yields the number of bytes in the object
>   representation of its operand. The operand is either an expression,
>   which is an unevaluated operand (Clause 5), or a parenthesized
>   type-id.

In this expression

```
sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0])
```

there are used two subexpressions with the sizeof operator.

This subexpression

```
sizeof(arr)
```

yields the number of bytes occupied by array `arr` (I suppose that `arr` is an array).

For example if you declared an array like

```
int arr[10];
```

then the compiler has to reserve memory that to hold 10 elements of type int. If for example `sizeof( int )` is equal to 4 then the compiler will reserve 10 * 4 = 40 bytes of memory.

Subexpression

```
sizeof(arr[0])
```

gives the number of bytes occupied by one element in the array. You could use any index as for example

```
sizeof(arr[1000])
```

because the expression is unevaluated. It is only important the size in bytes of the object (an element of the array) used inside the operator.

Thus if you know the total bytes that were reserved for an array

```
sizeof(arr)
```

and know how many bytes each element of the array occupies (all elements of an array have the same size) then you can calculate the number of elements in the array by using the formula

```
sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0])
```

Here is a simple relation. If you have an array of N elements of type T

```
T arr[N];
```

and you know the size of the memory occupied by the array then you can calculate the size of its element by using formula

```
sizeof( arr ) / N == size of an element of the array.
```

And vice verse

If you know the size of the memory occupied by the array and the size of its element you can calculate the number of elements in the array

```
sizeof( arr ) / sizeof( a[0] ) == N - number of elements in the array
```

The last expression you can rewrite also the following way

```
sizeof( arr ) / sizeof( T ) == N - number of elements in the array
```

because the elements of the array have type T and each element of the array occupies exactly the number of bytes that are required to allocate an object of type T.

Take into acccount that usually beginners make such an error. They pass an array as an argument to a function. For example let's assume that you have a function

```
void f( int a[] )
{
   // ...
}
```

And you pass to the function your array

```
int arr[10];
f(arr);
```

then the function uses the pointer to the first element of the array. In fact the function has declaration

```
void f( int *a )
{
   // ...
}
```

So if you write for example within the function

```
void f( int *a )
{
   size_t n = sizeof( a ) / sizeof( a[0] );
   // ...
}
```

then as `a` within the function is a pointer (it is not an array) then you will get something like

```
void f( int *a )
{
   size_t n = sizeof( int * ) / sizeof( int );
   // ...
}
```

Usually the size of a pointer equal to either 8 or 4 bytes depending of the used environment. And you won't get the number of elements. You will get some weird value.

Comment: I wonder, can i use int arr[10]; int length =  sizeof(arr)/sizeof(*arr); ??

Comment: @FitriHalim arr[0] is evaluated like *( arr + 0 ) that is the same as *arr. So these expressions are equivalent.

Comment: Which one is more readable/standard?

Comment: @FitriHalim It is opinion based.  I prefer to use sizeof( arr ) / sizeof( *arr ).

Answer (score 12):

`int` - is equal to 4 bytes
`sizeof(int)` it means: 1 * 4 = 4

`int arr[10]` - is holding 10 `int`
`sizeof(arr)` it means: 10 * 4 = 40, we got 10 `int` and every `int` got 4 bytes,, `arr` without the `[]` it means all the `arr`.

`sizeof(arr[0])` it means: 1 * 4 = 4

`sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0])` = 10*4 / 1*4 = 10,, and it is the length of the array.

Answer (score 8):

It only works if `arr` has not been decayed into a pointer, that is, it is an array type, *not* a pointer type.

`sizeof(arr)` is the total size occupied by the array.

`sizeof(arr[0])` is the size of the first element in the array. (Note that zero length arrays are not permitted in C++ so this element always exists if the array itself exists).

Since all the elements will be of the same size, the number of elements is `sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0])`.

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with an array (`some_type name[some_size]`) `sizeof(name)` is how many bytes the array occupies.  Dividing the total size of the array by the size of one element (`sizeof(name[0])`) gives you how many elements are in the array.

Answer (score 0):

c++ way to use extent, which allows u to get a number of elements in Nth dimension of the array.
see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/extent for details

```
int values[] = { 1 };

std::extent<decltype(values)>::value == 1
```

Comment: Could you extend your answer?

Comment: Only if you don't have an object. In that case, the more general `std::size()` is more elegant.

Answer (score -2):

Let's take an example like the `arr[]={1,2,4,3,5}`.

Then the size of the array will be 5 and the size of `arr[0]` will be "1" BECAUSE it consists of an element in it. Basically it's a subarray the from the above problem it will be 5/1 it will automatically returns the size of array =5.

Comment: Why do you think `sizeof(arr[0])` is 1? There's no implementation I know of for C++ where `int` is ever a single byte.

Comment: As mentioned above, the `sizeof` operator is giving the size of a variable **in bytes**. Thus, `sizeof(arr)` is `10 * sizeof(int)` in this case, and `sizeof(int)` is machine depended, and isn't 1 (either 2 or 4). Thus, we want to divide the size of the entire array in the size of a single variable in that array, therefore, we use the `/ sizeof(arr[0])` part.

Answer (score -3):

The difference is
int arr[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
here **arr is Pointer to array** and **&arr[0] is pointer of type Integer**

Comment: There are many good answers to this question already. Your answer does not match the question completely and does not add anything new. Please read [answer] questions