# How to understand "vector<int> avector (arr, arr + sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]) )"?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, stl

In the code below, what's the meaning of

```
vector<int> avector (arr, arr + sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]) );
```

in `main()`?

```
vector<int> bubbleSort(vector<int> avector) { //the vector for bubble sort
  for (int passnum = avector.size()-1; passnum > 0; passnum -= 1) {
      for (int i = 0; i < passnum; i++) {
          if (avector[i] > avector[i+1]) {
              int temp = avector[i];
              avector[i] = avector[i+1];
              avector[i+1] = temp;
          }
      }
  }
  return avector;
}

int main() {
    // Vector initialized using a static array
    static const int arr[] = {54,26,93,17,77,31,44,55,20};
    vector<int> avector (arr, arr + sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]) );

    vector<int> bvector = bubbleSort(avector);
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < bvector.size(); i++) {
        cout<<bvector[i]<< " ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you!

Jeff

Comment: maybe related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33523585/how-do-sizeofarr-sizeofarr0-work

Comment: If `arr` is an array (not a pointer), as it is in your code, then `sizeof(arr)` is the size in memory of the entire array, `sizeof(arr[0])` is the size of an element of the array, so `sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0])` is the number of elements in the array.   In the definition of `avector`,  `arr`  is converted to a pointer (equal to `&arr[0]`) and `arr + sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0])` is the address of one-past-the-end of `arr`.    So the code is creating a vector that contains all the elements of `arr`.   The technique does not work unless the compiler has visibility that `arr` is an array.

Comment: `sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0])` is a C hack for getting the size of an array. In C++ the initialization should be written `vector<int> avector(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr));`.

Answer (score 6):

```
vector<int> avector (arr, arr + sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]) );
```

initializes an `std::vector`, `avector`, from the `arr` C-style array.

The arguments are iterators. These iterators define a range of elements:

- `arr`: iterator to the first element of the range to be copied.
- `arr + sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0])`: iterator pointing the *past-the-end element* of the range to be copied.

---

The C++11 way would be to use the function templates [`std::cbegin()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin) and [`std::cend()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/end) for C-style arrays:

```
vector<int> avector(std::cbegin(arr), std::cend(arr));
```

This approach takes advantage of template argument deduction for inferring the size of the C-style array. This way is less error-prone since it requires less typing.

Comment: Thank you all for the detailed explanation! I started to learn C++ from the so-called modern C++ 14, so I had little idea of this old style. It's fun and interesting to learn. Thanks again!

Answer (score 5):

`n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0])` is the number of elements stored by the array.

`avector(arr, arr + sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0])` means copy the elements of the array `arr` to the vector `avector` from index `0` to `n-1` (inclusive)

Comment: Possibly better to say "`0` to `n-1` (inclusive)"   Saying "`0` to `n` (exclusive)" can be misinterpreted, particularly by non-native speakers (e.g. does it apply to both the `0` and the `n`, or [as you intend] to the `n`?)

Answer (score 2):

`avector` is constructed via copying all elements of `arr`.

it uses the following [constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) of the vector:

> ```
> template< class InputIt >
> vector( InputIt first, InputIt last, 
>         const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
> ```