# How to fix 'sizeof' not giving the expected result in an array parameter in a function

Tags: c++

So I'm doing a small task with C++ (never worked with this language before) and I encountered a problem with using 'sizeof' in an array to find its length. When I use it inside main() it works as expected, but if I use it inside a function it doesn't. It's clear that I'm missing some knowledge on very basic topics of C++ so I've come to find some guidance (I have checked the related questions of stack overflow and none provides some theory on what's happening, only ways of solving it in a different way).

I would also like to point out that I've seen different ways of making this work, but I would like to know why this one is not working and learn from it, thanks!

This is the code that I'm using:

```
// function example
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

// functions used
float max_value_array(float array[]);

int main()
{
  float rand_vec[] = {3, 2, 7, 5, 4};
  float max_num = max_value_array(rand_vec);
  cout << max_num;
}

float max_value_array(float array[])
{
  int len_array = sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]);

  float max_number = array[0];

  for (int i = 1; i < len_array; i++)
  {
    std::cout << array[i] << std::endl;
    if (array[i] > max_number)
    {
      max_number = array[i];
    }
  }

  return max_number;
}
```

(`<vector>` is included because I'm using it in a different part of the code)

What I would expect from this code is to return `7`, however I'm getting `3`. Upon investigation I found out that if I return `len_array` in `max_value_array` I'm getting `1` (and thus, getting the first element of the array as the loop doesn't start), which means that either the vector is not correctly passed, or that operation does not work. However if I return `array[3]` I get `5`, which means the array is passed correctly.

I also saw that when I return `sizeof(array)` I get `4`, and the same value if I return `sizeof(array[0])` (4). However, if I use `cout` in the main function to log both `sizeof(rand_vec)` and `sizeof(rand_vec[0])` I get respectively 520 and 4, which makes me think that there is something about `sizeof` and arrays that I'm not understanding.

Why does this happen?

Comment: Arrays decay into pointers when you pass them around. `sizeof` will return the size of that pointer (usually 8 or 4) inside the function receiving the array..

Comment: For get knowledge on sizeof(array) you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33523585/how-do-sizeofarr-sizeofarr0-work)

Comment: Change `float max_value_array(float array[])` to `template < size_t N> float max_value_array(float (&array)[N])` to have a reference of the array and `sizeof array` will give the correct value.

Comment: The fix consists in passing both the array and its length: float max_value_array(float *, size_t); In the case you know the size at compile time pass a std::array

Comment: TL;DR: Don't use inbuilt arrays, use `std::vector` or `std::array`.